# Travelling Salesman Constructive Heuristics

Tags: algorithm, heuristics, traveling-salesman

Say, we have a circular list representing a solution of the traveling salesman problem. This list is initially empty.

If the user is allowed to enter a city and it's coordinate one by one, what heuristics could be used to *insert* those coordinates into the already existing tour?

---

An example uses the nearest neighbor heuristic : it inserts the new coordinate after the nearest coordinate already in the tour.

What are some other options (pseudo-code if possible).

Comment: You don't need to give me code. If it were homework I'd ask for code, I don't need any. Just want to optimize my app and see what my options are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course generalize the idea you have mentioned:

Define `k'th_path(v) = minimum weight of a path including max{k,not_visited cities} cities`

Note that calculating the k'th path is `O(|V|^k)` [this bound is not tight]

**Special cases**:

- For `k=1` you get the nearest neighbor, as you suggested.
- for `k=|V|` you get an optimal solution [note it will be very expansive to calculate].

Comment: Thanks, amit!! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for : no code, just the explanation of a heuristic. Can't thank you enough.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of construction heuristics you can use, such as First Fit, First Fit Decreasing, Best Fit, Best Fit Decreasing and Cheapest Insertion.
Those constructions heuristics are applied on bin packing normally, but they can be converted to TSP too. [Documentation about those heuristics is here.](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta1/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3546)

Since you're only inserting 1 unassigned entity at at time, all of these basically revert to what you call *nearest neighbor heuristic* (with a slight variation on ties), but note that that is not what they usually call Nearest Neighbor. Nearest Neighbor always adds to the end of the line, the nearest neighbor of all unassigned entities.

Now, what you really want, is a decent solution, without having to restart your entire construction heuristics. That's harder: welcome to [repeated planning and real-time planning](http://blog.athico.com/2011/07/real-time-planning-with-drools-planner.html) (and [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Beta1/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#repeatedPlanning)). I am working on a open source example for TSP and vehicle routing that does real-time planning.

Comment: I don't think he (Korion) understand this.

Comment: Because you don't understand it, David :D? Thanks, Geoffrey!

Answer (score 0):

There are not other heuristic because TSP is always about to find the nearest coordinate. At least I don't know an algorithm that can insert a coordinate and knows the nearest coordinate but there are plenty algorithm to find a good tour. A good heuristic is for example the Christofides algorithm, it works only in euklidian space but it give you a guarantee of the solution to be within 3/2 of the optimum. It's not very easy to code. Especially the edmond blossom v algorithm is for an expert skill. The importance of a guarantee isn't high enough because how would you explain that your method can deliver non-sense in some rare situation?

Comment: There are no other heuristics? I doubt it. Any resources for this claim?

Comment: @amit: There are plenty heuristic to find a good tour but none of them works with an insert method or maybe I just don't understand his question.

Comment: There are other heuristics, David. Farthest insertion, cheapest insertion.

Comment: @Korion: I really don't know why you are so happy. Your question is really vague. I give you an answer and also a very good heuristic.

Comment: Why are you so mean? You down-vote all good answers here for no reason... I could re-phrase my question for you, but I don't see the point : I got the answers I needed.

Comment: Christofides is a good heuristic though. I would up-vote you if you hadn't down-voted everyone else.